# Django 500 error for not-existing url in Debug=False

Tags: django, django-urls, django-errors

I'm using Django 2.1.3 in python 3.6.7.
assume that I have this URL path:

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

If I navigate to `/ad` while the `DEBUG = True`, I see normal Django 404 error page:

[image]

But if I make `DEBUG = False` then the server shows up the **500.htm** to me instead of **404.html** for invalid URL `/ad` (that matches none of the URL patterns).

The **404.html** is showing up for a valid URL that raises 404 error. (like when a **not-existing object** query occurs with `get_object_or_404` function)

here is my `/templates` directory structure:

```
/templates
    400.html
    403.html
    404.html
    500.html
    index.html
    ...
```

So, How should I tell Django to show 404 error in production (in addition to development) if the request URL matches none of the URL patterns?

Note:

- According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#the-404-page-not-found-view), if I have a `404.html` in the root templates directory, this 404.html will be used with the default error handler.

Update:

I figured out that it's happed because that the `defaults.page_not_found` raises a `Resolver404`, and that's caused by :

> the path passed to resolve() doesn’t map to a view

which is the exactly what happened,(the `/ad` don't match any view)

here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
              path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that one of my custom template context processors uses `django.urls.resolve` and as the path don't match any view, the `resolve` raises **Resolver404**.

So I fix that context processor and the problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a 404 view that will render when no URL match. Then you need to set it `hander404` in `urls.py`

```
handler404 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_page_not_found_view'
```

For more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Comment: I just need to change the error page template, but I do that and gets the same result, The **500** error page shows up if the URL matches none of the URL patterns!

Comment: add your urls.py

Comment: you need to add handler404 in urls.py